# TC (Traffic Control) to control bandwidth

Tags: centos, iptables, tc

I'm having an issue with a bandwidth script that I've been using for a while to limit the outgoing bandwidth on a port.

It worked fine at the beginning until I wanted to change the outgoing port speed. I switched it to a higher number ( 200mbit to 400mbit ) and I restarted the script. For some reason the new bandwidth limit didn't take and the old limit is still there. I have the script set-up as an init service. This is what part of the code looks like.

```
# Interface
interface=eth0

# Define the upload, follow units can be
upload_limit=400mbit

start() {
    # Start the tc configuration and set all packets default to 10
    /sbin/tc qdisc add dev $interface root handle 1:0 htb default 10

    # Set default speed for all packets
    /sbin/tc class add dev $interface parent 1:0 classid 1:10 htb rate 1000mbit ceil 1000mbit prio 0
    # Set speeds for packets marked with 20
    /sbin/tc class add dev $interface parent 1:0 classid 1:20 htb rate $upload_limit ceil $upload_limit prio 0

    # Mark packets for port 182 to 20 so that tc can handle the traffic.
    /sbin/iptables -A OUTPUT -t mangle -p tcp --sport 182 -j MARK --set-mark 20
    /sbin/service iptables save

    # Assign it to appropriate qdisc
    tc filter add dev $interface parent 1:0 prio 0 protocol ip handle 20 fw flowid 1:20
}

stop() {
    /sbin/tc qdisc del dev $interface root
}
```

Can anyone offer me any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, the reason for the old rule still being in place is that the iptables rule that causes "the magic" is still there, as you have a line that adds it and no line to remove it. Check your iptables rules file. You should have a bunch of lines similar to the old version (port) of "iptables -D OUTPUT -t mangle -p tcp --sport 182 -j MARK --set-mark 20". (as everytime the script is executed, you create a new one and save it afterwards)

Try to put an Iptables command on stop() function to clean the mangle table rules. Something like this:
   /sbin/iptables -D OUTPUT -t mangle -p tcp --sport 182 -j MARK --set-mark 20
   /sbin/service iptables save